# Design upgrade to iPad 3 filenames

Tags: ios5, filenames

I have an app which needs to be upgraded all the PNG files to also support retina. How is this done in regards to filenames when I have a folder with about 40 files for buttons etc.

Sorry for the "stupid" question but we all have to start somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

For images within the app, just double the size of the image and put an @2x suffix on the image. For example, if you have a 100px x 44px button image named MyButton.png. You'd create a 200px x 88px image named MyButton@2x.png. Place that button in the same folder as the other image and the OS will take care of the rest for you.

Secondly,
If you're worried about nomenclature for the Launch Images and the image icons I'd recommend reading up on the freshly updated programming guide and human interface guidelines.

Lastly,
I created a nice little inforgraphic that combines the requirements into an easier to read format. Feel free to check it out. It lists what's required, the names of the new image files and the sizes apple requires for those images. Hope this helps!

[Programming Guide - Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

[Human Interface Guidelines - Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW15)

[iOS Image Guide - Inforgraphic](http://blog.metaphx.com/2012/03/08/ios-image-guideline-infographic/)